# Search node/text() from (Result Tree Fragment)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

my templates (XSLT 1.0)

> ```
> <xsl:template name="doo">
> ```

```
    <xsl:variable name="nodelist">
        <root>
            <a size="12" number="11">
                <sex>male</sex>
                Hulk
            </a>
            <a size="12" number="11">
                <sex>male</sex>
                Steven XXXXXXXXXXX
            </a>
        </root>
    </variable>


    <xsl:call-template name="findString">
       <xsl:with-param name="content1" select="$nodelist"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

> ```
> </xsl:template>
> ```

```
<xsl:template name="findString">
    <xsl:param name="content1" select="."></xsl:param>

    <!-- here i need to search the text() XXXXXXXXXXX from $content1 and replace them-->

</xsl:template>
```

is this possible like

```
for each node in Tree Fragment from myvariable
if node/text()='xxxxxxxx'
  do something
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT: copy Nodes and modify them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126641/xslt-copy-nodes-and-modify-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With xslt version=1.0 you can use a extension "not-set".

```
<xsl:call-template name="findString">
   <xsl:with-param name="content1" select="exsl:node-set($nodelist)"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

To make it  woke you have to add following lines.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">
```

Update:
Based on solution from [Mads Hansen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127524/2115381)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:template name="doo">
        <xsl:variable name="nodelist">
            <root>
                <a size="12" number="11">
                    <sex>male</sex>
                    Hulk
                </a>
                <a size="12" number="11">
                    <sex>male</sex>
                    Steven XXXXXXXXXXX
                </a>
            </root>
        </xsl:variable>
        aaa
        <xsl:call-template name="findString">
            <xsl:with-param name="content1" select="exsl:node-set($nodelist)"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="doo" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="findString">
        <xsl:param name="content1" select="."></xsl:param>

        <!-- here i need to search the text() XXXXXXXXXXX from $content1 and replace them-->
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="mytext" select="$content1"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <!--Identity template will copy all matched nodes and apply-templates-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="mytext">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="mytext"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Specialized template to match on text nodes that contain the "findString" value-->
    <xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'XXXXXXXXXXX')]"  mode="mytext">
        <xsl:variable name="findString" select="'XXXXXXXXXXX'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replaceString" select="'YYYYYYYYYYYY'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., $findString), 
                                    $replaceString, 
                                    substring-after(., $findString))"/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: ok, and how can i find the 'XXXXXXXXXXX' and modify them? its very important that i could use my local varible

Comment: Have a look to the update. But this s almost the same as in your previous question.

Comment: wow, this is crazy shit, i did not know the mode="" Tag. Thank you